# How to pass url parameters to views with Route::view method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my code in Laravel :`

```
Route::view('/welcome/{name}','welcome',['name'=>'name']);
```

I want to know is it possible get and pass {name} parameter  to view by Route::view  or not?
I know that we can do it with Route::get :

```
Route::get('/welcome/{name}', function($name){
return view('welcome',['name'=>$name]);
});
```

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: yes, I have try it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pass parameter use the segment. Try this in your view:

```
{{ Request::segment(2) }}
```